# Why physically realizable systems should have Hermitian symmetry?

Tags: signal-processing

I have read that For any physically realizable system `H(f)` has Hermitian symmetry. That is `H( f ) = H*(− f )` and that fact can be used to show that its magnitude is an even function and its phase can be expressed as an
odd function.

I came across this statement in many books. But what is the 'physical explanation of this statement? Why the magnitude response has to be an even function and why the phase response has to be an odd function for physically realizable sytems?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the standard practice of reporting all measurements of observables of any physically realizable systems in terms of strictly real values.  And the DFT of any strictly real set of measurements is conjugate symmetric.

If you assume that some measurement or behavior of a physical system is an imaginary component of a complex value, then conjugate symmetry of the DFT or FT is no longer guaranteed.